# Correspondence between width and height argument and centimeters in ggsave()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to save a plot using ggsave() so that it has exactly 17.8 cm width. 
How do the numbers entered into the ggsave() 'width' argument correspond to centimeters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggsave("figure1.pdf", width = 17.8, units = "cm")
```

See `?ggsave`, it's all there. Default unit is inches.